# When does pthread_t have 0?

Tags: pthreads

I created threads using pthread_create() in RHEL 7.2.
pthread_create returns 0, but *thread (1st parameter) is 0.

do you know the reason that thread id is 0?

```
pthread_t thread[6];
int nArg;

int nThread = pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, funcA, &nArg);
if(0 > nThread)
    printf("failed");
else
    printf("thread started: %ld", thread[0]);
```

Output: 
thread started: 0

Comment: Please change your code as I suggest in my answer, and report back here.

Comment: Thanks. I modifed my code as you said, then found it returns 11 from pthread_create().

Comment: Glad it helped. Errno 11 seems to be 'Resource temporarily unavailable', maybe you have too many threads running in the system already? Or you hit a per-process limit.

Comment: Does total count of thread running relate to stack size? The stack size is set to 4194304 kbytes as returned by the command ulimit -s.

Comment: How many threads are running in the system? If you are low on RAM, having 4 MB of RAM per thread could use up too much total stack space. Or you are hitting the max nr of processes, check with ulimit -u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead checking the return value against exactly zero. Only if return value is 0 did the thread creation succeed.

The errno manpage says 'Valid error numbers are all positive numbers'. For example, on Linux, the errno error numbers seem to be roughly betwen 0 and 200.

Also, print the message corresponding to the errno error number you get, using e.g. perror().

Answer (score 2):

> I created threads using pthread_create() in RHEL 7.2. pthread_create
>   returns 0, but *thread (1st parameter) is 0.
>
> do you know the reason that thread id is 0?

Assuming for the moment that it really *is* 0, what of it?  That presupposes that `pthread_t` is an arithmetic type, which is not specified by the current version of POSIX, but if so, then 0 is a valid value for it.  There is no documented significance for specific thread identifier values, and in particular, there is no reason to think that a thread shouldn't be assigned 0 as its identifier if that is a valid value of type `pthread_t`.

Since you also mentioned the return value of `pthread_create`, I suppose you may think there is some kind of relationship between that and the thread ID.  No such relationship is documented, except that the value of the thread ID is defined after `pthread_create()` returns only if the return value is exactly 0.

But that does point to an issue in your code, which @ErikAlapää first pointed out: `pthread_create()` is in the group of functions that return an error number directly on failure, ***not*** the group that return -1 on failure and expect you to consult `errno` for the error number.  Error numbers are positive, so your condition `if(0 > nThread)` cannot be relied upon to detect whether `pthread_create` failed.  You should test against exactly 0:

```
if (0 != nThread) {
    printf("failed");
} else {
    printf("thread started: %lu", (unsigned long) thread[0]);
}
```

Note also the format change and cast in the second `printf()` call.  You need the second argument to have exactly the type corresponding to formatting directive (formerly `%ld`, but now `%lu`) and that's `unsigned long int`.  The cast is valid is long as `pthread_t` is an arithmetic or pointer type, and in practice, the compiler can be relied upon to reject the code if it's anything else -- a structure type, say.  Given that a cast is necessary (but possibly not sufficient) to obtain a known type, an *unsigned* type is safer because the conversion then has defined behavior in the event that the original value is out of range for the target type.  If you have a type mismatch, as you could have had in your original code, then the behavior is undefined, and among the more likely of the uncountably many possible manifestations of such UB is that "0" is printed despite `thread[0]` being nonzero.

With all that said, I do not reproduce your issue, even with your original, flawed code.  I'm inclined to suspect that your `pthread_create` call is failing, possibly because you're using a C library built without thread support, or linking dummy pthreads routines instead of functional ones.  Be sure when you build to provide the right options for a pthreads program.  For example, if you're compiling with `gcc` then you would want to provide the `-pthread` option.  If you have separate compilation and link steps, then use that option for both.

Answer (score 0):

The `pthread_t` type is opaque according to POSIX. It can be any type. In particular, it is not required to be an arithmetic type (pointer or integer). A conforming implementation of POSIX threads can use a `struct` for `pthread_t`.

If `pthread_t` happens to be an integer type, there is no prohibition against it being zero. It could be the index of a thread in some array, such that the first thread gets position zero.

We are not surprised that the standard input file descriptor is zero, after all.

Comment: I see that POSIX changed its position on type `pthread_t` over time.  It used to be specified to be an arithmetic type, but now is explicitly excluded from that specification.